# HttpWebResponse ReadAsync time out

Tags: c#, async-await, stream, timeout

I try to read stream of HttpWebResponse using await/async:

```
    async static Task testHttpWebClientAsync()        
    {

        string url = "http://localhost/1.txt";
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        req.Method = "GET";
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)await req.GetResponseAsync();            
        Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
        stream.ReadTimeout = 10 * 1000;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (await stream.ReadAsync(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0)                           
        {
            //time out exception never thrown
        }
    }
```

But it doesn't work, it never time out on ReadAsync.
For comparison a non-async version work perfectly with the same localhost test server:

```
    static void testHttpWebClient()
    {            
        string url = "http://localhost/1.txt";
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
        req.Method = "GET";
        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
        Stream stream = resp.GetResponseStream();
        stream.ReadTimeout = 10 * 1000;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        while (stream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length) > 0)
        {
            //time out exception thrown here
        }
    }
```

The above code is tested in a console application:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        testHttpWebClient();
        MainAsync(args).GetAwaiter().GetResult();
    }
    async static Task MainAsync(string[] args)
    {
        await testHttpWebClientAsync();            
    }
```

But this is not relevant to the problem, indeed I find the problem in a WinForms project and create the console project to test the problem.

For reference, the test server code is something like:

```
                    int c = 10;
                    byte[] ba = new byte[1024];
                    SendHeader(sHttpVersion, sMimeType,(int) ba.Length*c, " 200 OK", ref mySocket);
                    for (int k = 0; k < c; k++)
                    {
                        //set break point here
                        SendToBrowser(ba, ref mySocket);
                    }
```

There are several similar topics on SO, but it seems that none of them solve this problem. From API design perspective, obviously there is no reason that ReadAsync() doesn't time out just like Read() does, ReadAsync only need to watch both the socket and an internal timer event, this is how Task.Delay() works. This has nothing to do with CancellationToken,etc because we don't need to cancel anything, even ReadAsync has a version that accept CancellationToken.

So this question is both for a solution for the problem, and why ReadAsync doesn't just time out as expected.

Comment: Why don't you set the timeout on the actual request? `req.TimeOut = 10 * 1000`?

Comment: @ Çöđěxěŕ first, it doesn't work, too. Second, req.TimeOut is about the time out of req.GetResponse, not read operation. Indeed, req.ReadWriteTimeout doesn't work, too.

Comment: How about using a `NetworkStream`, have you tried that?

Comment: Never heard of it before... lets focus on above code.

Comment: The main issue is because it's returning a `Task`, you are awaiting this task *without* a cancellation token. How do you expect it to timeout/cancel, not all streams support timing out and the reason I mentioned using `NetworkStream`...

Comment: I don't think cancellation token is for this. If a stream doesn't support time out , it will throw exception when you set time out for it.

Comment: @jw_ did you try to supress `stream.ReadTimeout = 10 * 1000;`

Comment: @ sayah imad why do I supress it? Then how to set the time out?

Comment: Can you post the code invoking `testHttpWebClientAsync`? What type of application is this? Console?

Comment: `From API design perspective, obviously there is no reason that ReadAsync() doesn't time out just like Read() does` And yet, that's how it was implemented. And I agree that it doesn't make any sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Asynchronous APIs on `HttpWebRequest` (and on `WebClient` since it uses `HttpWebRequest` internally) do not use timeouts internally. While I can't really explain the reasoning behind it, **this is by design**.

This is especially apparent [in the Write logic of the `ConnectStream` (used internally by `HttpWebResponse`)](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/_ConnectStream.cs,996):

```
if (async) {
    m_Connection.BeginMultipleWrite(buffers, m_WriteCallbackDelegate, asyncResult);
}
else {
    SafeSetSocketTimeout(SocketShutdown.Send);
    m_Connection.MultipleWrite(buffers);
}
```

`SafeSetSocketTimeout` is the method responsible of setting the timeout on the underlying socket. As you can see, it's deliberately skipped on the async path. It's the same thing for read operations, but the code is more convoluted so it's harder to show.

Therefore, you really have only two solutions:

1. Implement the timeout yourself (usually with a timer that calls `.Abort()` on the `HttpWebRequest`)
2. Use `HttpClient` instead

Comment: But why won't stream.ReadTimeout throw an exception? And no documentation seems mentions this time out Behavior. So is this considered a bug?

Comment: `stream.ReadTimeout` doesn't throw an exception because it will work if you use `Read` instead of `ReadAsync` (which isn't known at the moment when you set `ReadTimeout`. And the behavior is documented: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.timeout?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Net_HttpWebRequest_Timeout  `In the case of asynchronous requests, the client application implements its own time-out mechanism. `

Comment: Can you post an example of using HttpClient with await to implement exactly the above functions?

Comment: “In the case of asynchronous requests, the client application implements its own time-out mechanism. ” So the reasoning and problem behind the scene may be: true traditional async code will deal with time out by themselves after the function call returns as the doc says, but ayns/await is to use sync code sytle to implement async operations, so the API is indeed sync code which should let the function itself deal with time out. They seems to confuse between true async and async/wait.

Comment: Because they generally use the same principle for all the APIs, maybe there won't be an awaitable function that will time out (except for Task.Delay whose purpose is to time out). If so, will any API of HttpClient be awaited and trigger time out?

Comment: Been googling this for a while today, and a couple of points I've found so far:  1) in .net *framework*, HttpClient is built on top of HttpWebRequest/Response.  So anything that's an issue in HttpWebRequest will also be an issue in HttpClient unless you switch to .net core.  And 2) Haven't found a work-around that would cover a GetResponseStream.CopyTo(memoryStream).  Either sync or async, it just doesn't seem to pay attention to read timeouts in that situation.